# How does Voldemort know who is summoning him through the Dark Mark?

Tags: harry-potter

How does Voldemort know who is summoning him through the Dark Mark? Does he imbue the Dark Mark with Legilimens to know who summons him?

Also, if multiple Death Eaters are summoning him from different places at the same time, does he get summoned to the one who summons him first?

Comment: Magic? That's just a guess.

Comment: Like Caller ID?

Comment: Do you have any proof that the Dark Mark is in itself a summons, and not just some kind of notification? Hard to think of Voldemort allowing anyone to "summon" him anywhere.

Comment: @ZevSpitz - yes, it is explicitly called a summons. See my answer ;)

Comment: @Mithrandir There's nothing inherently summoning in a phone call or an email, even though both can be used for that purpose. The Dark Mark could also work the same way.

Comment: ...maybe the mark is CA-signed?

Comment: I think some of the confusion stems from how the word “summon” is used.  I.e. does it ‘**pull**’ or does it ‘**prompt**’?  As one of the answers asserts, the Dark Mark **pulls**.  However, that isn't the only possible usage of the word:  one of us can be *summoned* to appear before a magistrate via letter or messenger, but the summons isn't that with compels the person to attend — it usually is the strongarms acting on behalf of the magistrate.

Answer (score 29):

## He doesn't know.

We see the Mark from his perspective:

> At once, Harry's scar felt as though it had split open again. His true surroundings vanished: He was Voldemort, and the skeletal wizard before him was laughing toothlessly at him; he was enraged at the summons he felt - he had warned them, he had told them to summon him for nothing less than Potter. If they were mistaken...
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, chapter 23</sub>

We see that he doesn't know what he was summoned for. It's not clear if he knows *who*, but we see that he knows where to go - it *summons* him there.

Comment: But there's a kerfluffle over who gets to be the one to summon him, right?

Comment: No. Someone was trying to *stop* someone else from doing it cause they didn't want to until they were sure, but here Bellatrix just taps without the fighting.

Comment: Oh wait, yes, earlier. It was more about authority then, I think.

Comment: I read this as Voldemort's complete disdain and uncaring for everything and everyone -- one of those annoying hangers-on whose name he can't be bothered to recall just pressed the Dark Mark.

Comment: @Mithrandir Who is the skeletal wizard in the quote?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai - Grindelwald.

Comment: "Summons" in this context doesn't mean what you think it means. Voldemort isn't "summoned" as in he is compelled to go to the Death Eater. The "summons" is a request for an audience with Voldemort. Voldemort clearly has the authority to refuse to give audience if he wanted to (surely he would not sanction otherwise?).

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister - right, got that after the discussion on the question...

Answer (score 19):

My understanding is when a minion activates the Dark Mark, it acts as a beacon. So from that Voldemort can Apparate and it draws him to the location of the person who triggered the Dark Mark. He may or may not know who triggered it until he arrives.

The beacon works both ways. If Voldemort activates the mark, then his followers can Apparate and appear near him.

Comment: My memory of the books, such as it is, agrees with this answer. IIRC, when V activates his Mark, his followers explicitly do *not* all Apparate in at the same time, indicating that it is a matter of choice (and some don't come at all). If it works the same both ways, then the Dark Mark is a beacon, like you described.